# Copy values from multiple columns in same row VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a VBA noob with a massive table of analysis results where each row is containing results from a different date. I'm looking for values in certain columns, and they are some times empty. When they are, I'm not interested in them. The values I want are supposed to be copied to a new sheet to be collected in a smaller table.

I have written a script where I loop through the rows in the `masterTable`, and I am able to identify the rows with the values I'm interested in. However, I am not able to copy the value from the different cells in the identified row to a new sheet.

I've tried using `Union` to make a `range` inlcuding the columns that are relevant for copying.

```
Dim searchCells As Range
Dim masterTable As Range

Set searchCells = Union(Columns("R"), Columns("S"), Columns("T"), Columns("X"), Columns("Z"), Columns("AF"), Columns("AQ"), Columns("AT"), Columns("AY"), Columns("AV"), Columns("BB"), Columns("BD"), Columns("BG"))
Set masterTable = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A3:BG2022")

a = 1
For i = 1 To masterTable.Rows.Count
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(searchCells(i).Value) <> 0 Then ' look for values among the relevant columns in row(i).
    Debug.Print "Found data at "; i
    Worksheets("Sheet0").searchCells.Rows(i).Copy ' copy data from searchCells
    Worksheets("Results").Range("C1").Offset(a, 0).paste ' paste data to destination
    a = a + 1 ' increment destination row offset
  End If
Next
```

My idea of the `searchCells` are not working, as I "find data" in all rows, and I'm not able to run the `.Copy` and the `.Paste` methods. All help is appreaciated!

EDIT: upon compilation VBA throws the following error on the copy-line:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Are you trying to only copy the populated cells, or the entire row (for those columns) if any of the cells is populated?

Comment: That's actually a good question. Initially, I'd like to copy the given cells from the entire row. I guess I'll do the sorting later.

Comment: Your If statement seems wrong. There should not be a `.Value` inside?

Comment: Good point. Though it doesn't solve the problem :p See edit

Comment: yeah, because as i see, you wanted to check the entire row. Use `countA(Intersect(SearchCells, Rows(i)))`

Comment: The compiler error is due to the wrong use of `.Value` mentionned above, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the relevant rows (for those columns only) where there is data in at least one cell, you could use:

```
Dim searchCells           As Range
Dim masterTable           As Range
Dim rRow                  As Range

Set searchCells = Range("R:T,X:X,Z:Z,AF:Af,AQ:Aq,AT:AT,AV:AV,AY:AY,BB:BB,BD:BD,BG:BG")
Set masterTable = Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("A3:BG2022")

a = 1
For i = 1 To masterTable.Rows.Count
    Set rRow = Intersect(searchCells, searchCells.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rRow) <> 0 Then    ' look for values among the relevant columns in row(i).
        Debug.Print "Found data at "; i
        rRow.Copy Worksheets("Results").Range("C1").offset(a, 0)    ' paste data to destination
        a = a + 1    ' increment destination row offset
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! `rRow` doesn't seem to get any values from the `Set` code, but the solution was to add `Worksheets("Sheet0").Range(...)` to the code. Works like a charm! :-D